# WPF Control style is not applied at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my project I'm using [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/). I had to override the default style for [WatermarkTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WatermarkTextBox&referringTitle=Home). On first sight it was ok - application launches and style is being applied, but when I look at designer - all controls except WatermarkTextBox have applied designs and WatermarkTextBox has not.]

My resource dictionary file:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
                xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework" 
                xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit">
```

And style (all static resources are defined in the same file at beginning):

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type xctk:WatermarkTextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type xctk:WatermarkTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="34" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="34" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DarkGrayBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource GrayBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,3,4,3" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource OpenSans}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="MaxLines" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="WatermarkTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                Foreground="{StaticResource GrayBrush}" 
                                Focusable="False" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:WatermarkTextBox}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        CornerRadius="2"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >

                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                      Panel.ZIndex="10" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_WatermarkHost"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Watermark}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding WatermarkTemplate}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                          Margin="6,0,0,0"
                                          Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </Grid>

                    <wpf:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <wpf:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <wpf:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <wpf:VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </wpf:VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <wpf:VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <wpf:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DarkBlueColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </wpf:VisualState>
                            <wpf:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource LightGrayColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </wpf:VisualState>
                            <wpf:VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly" />
                        </wpf:VisualStateGroup>
                    </wpf:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_WatermarkHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static system:String.Empty}">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_WatermarkHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have defined my styles in Styles.xaml file. and I'm referencing it in each UserControl file. For example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And I want to apply this style for WatermarkTextBox:

```
    <xctk:WatermarkTextBox Margin="0,0,0,20" Text="{Binding MyField, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <xctk:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
            <TextBlock Text="Watermark text"
                       Style="{x:Null}" />
        </xctk:WatermarkTextBox.Watermark>
    </xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
```

So, as I mentioned - I see the style is applied at runtime, but in VS2013 designer it uses default style for control. I want to see the right style at design time. Is it possible?

Are the any restrictions for resource file size of anything such? My file contains ~2000lines of XAML code and there are defined about 40 styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in version mismatch of NuGet packages. Root application was using 2.4 version and module used 2.3 version. This mismatch also caused many TargetInvocationException and NullReferenceException exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give your code of resourcedictionary

to App.xaml. And then call it in UserControl